# compiling python script to exe with py2exe, getting error

Tags: python, selenium, py2exe, helium

So I have a script called papercutter.py and a setup.py that is set up as follows according to the py2exe tutorial:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['papercutter.py'])
```

So following the tutorial, i run **python setup.py py2exe** and it looks successful:

```
c:\Codes>python setup.py install
running install
running build
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\UNKNOWN-0.0.0-py3.6.egg-info
Writing C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\UNKNOWN-0.0.0-py3.6.egg-info
```

but when I run the next step, **python setup.py py2exe**, I get error:

```
c:\Codes>python setup.py py2exe
running py2exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup(console=['papercutter.py'])
  File "C:\Python\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 188,        in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 267,      in _run
    builder.analyze()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 157, in analyze
    self.mf.import_package(modname[:-2])
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 91, in      import_package
    self.import_hook(name)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 117, in import_hook
    module = self._gcd_import(name)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 267, in _gcd_import
    return self._find_and_load(name)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 320, in _    find_and_load
    self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 352, in _scan_code
    for what, args in self._scan_opcodes(code):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 381, in     _scan_opcodes
    yield "store", (names[oparg],)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Note: this is the tutorial I am following: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Also note: I am using py2exe 0.9.2.0 and python 3.6.0. I think these should be fine together.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is at the bottom of the Traceback.  Seems like you have an indexing problem with a tuple.  Indexes are 0 based in Python.

Comment: I don't use any arrays in my script though. I just go to a website and click a few things

Comment: The release notes for cx_freeze.  http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes.html

Answer (score 1):

Currently py2exe supports Python up to 3.4